# TestNG on Windows only runs the test with the lowest priority

Tags: maven, testng, maven-3

We have a Selenium test suite running on a Windows VM. We've just switched to TestNG from JUnit, mainly because we wanted to have a clean way of setting the test order (having stuff like `aDoThis`, `bThenThat` is kinda ugly), and we've run in the weirdest thing.

Running locally on macOS, the test suite runs fine from 1-20. Running the tests on Windows (our VM runs Server 2012 R2, but we also tested on a laptop with Windows 10), the test suite only runs the tests with the lowest priority (I have even tried setting the same priority across all tests and they all ran successfully).

We are running JDK 12.0.2 and Maven 3.6.1 on all machines. This is the relevant part from the pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>12</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

We haven't set up a `testng.xml`, because we don't really want to do anything crazy, we just want to run all our tests in order and, locally at least, we were able to run the tests in the proper order without setting the test suite XML up.

Comment: Why not upgrade to jUnit5? https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-execution-order

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add a sample project (maybe post it on github and share a link) that can be used to reproduce the problem? If priorities have been set, then TestNG should honor it as long as its within the same class. I dont quite recollect what is the behavior of priorities across classes. Priority AFAIK was always meant to be used to introduce a soft dependency amongst test methods within the same class.